# How do I place table data <td> after each other without empty spaces?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

If a row[''] is empty. the value isn't going to be echoed (it's not in the code at the moment, I just going to add an if statement on every `<td>`)

At the moment if some of the `<td>`s are empty then it's all being echoed like this, with empty spaces all over:

```
- - - -
-   - 
  - -
```

I don't want empty spaces at all. I want it to be like this:

```
- - - -
- -
```

How can I do this?

```
<table style="width:100%">
         <tr>
      <td>body:<?php echo $row['body']; ?></td>
      <td>Length:<?php echo $row['Length']; ?></td>
      <td>Weight:<?php echo $row['Weight'];</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>asd: <?php echo $row['asd']; ?></td>
      <td>vbn: <?php echo $row['vb']; ?></td>
      <td>zxc: <?php echo $row['zxc']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: [Displaying posts in three columns using php](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34503569/3184785). Test for the row being empty and `continue` in the first loop. It should do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<table style="width:100%">
<?php
$cols = 0;
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
  if ($value != ""){

    if ($cols % 3 == 0 && $cols != 0) {
      echo"</tr><tr>";
    }
    $cols++;
    echo "<td>$key: $value</td>";
  }
}
echo "</tr>";
?>
</table>
```

Comment: You don't actually want the table rows that you echo outside of the foreach loop correct?

Comment: Why does it being echoed twice?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
<td>body:<?php if(empty($row['body'])) { echo '&nbsp'; } else { echo $row['body']; } ?></td>
```

Or simpler:

```
<td>body:<?php echo (empty($row['body'])) ? '&nbsp' : $row['body']; ?></td>
```

In other words, echo out `&nbsp;` if the value is empty.

---

Or rather, now that I better understand your issue:

```
<?php if(!empty($row['body'])) { echo '<td>body:' . $row['body'] . '</td>'; } ?>
```

I thought at first your issue was the one where if you do `<td></td>` the browser doesn't even render the empty space but collapses that cell as if it doesn't exist. But apparently what you want is to suppress cells for which you have no data, which means expand the if statement to the whole TD rather than the innards of the TD.

Comment: Doesnt seem to work. There is still an empty space when I do that.